# What does searching for "Find all word forms" do in Word for Mac 2016?

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, search

The find and replace box in Word for Mac 2016 includes a "Find all word forms" option. When I check this box, I expected it to find every word in the attached screenshot, but it only finds 3 words:

[image]

If I uncheck "Find all word forms", exactly the same 3 words are found as below. So what function does "Find all word forms" serve?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### So what function does "Find all word forms" serve?

It will find related words, using a grammar-based lexicon.

> Find All Word Forms: When selected, the operation finds related word forms. For example, searching for "eat" would find "eaten" and "ate."

Source [Search Options | Advanced Find-and-Replace Tools in Word | InformIT](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=422953&seqNum=2)

And

> You can find words that contain the same
>   letters using wildcards, but choosing "all word forms" allows you to search
>   for, say, "is" and also find "are," "were," "be," etc. The search is based
>   on a grammar-based lexicon.

Source [Question about the meaning of "Find all word forms" option - Microsoft Office Word Forum - WordBanter](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=97509)

In your particular case, the lexicon does not think that "adequacy" and "adequate" are related words.